# MongoDB Aggregate List of Object IDs

Tags: database, mongodb, performance, aggregate

I'm trying to create an interface which gives our team the ability to build relatively simple queries to segment customers and aggregate data about those customers. In addition to this, I want to build a "List" feature" that allows users to upload a CSV that can be separately generated for more complex one-off queries. In this scenario, I'm trying to figure out the best way to query the database.

My main question is how the $in operator works. The example below has an aggregate which tries to check if a primary key (object ID) is in an array of object IDs.

How well does the $in operator perform? I'm mostly wondering how this query will run – does it loop over the array and look for documents that match each value in the array for N lookups, or will it loop over all of the documents in the database and for each one, loop over the array and check if the field matches?

```
db.getCollection('customers').aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
       '_id': { $in: ['ObjectId("idstring1")','ObjectId("idstring2")'...'ObjectId("idstring5000")']}
      }
    }
])
```

If that's not how it works, what's the most efficient way of aggregating a set of documents given a bunch of object IDs? Should I just do the N lookups manually and pipe the documents into the aggregation?

Comment: Out of my experience I can say `$in` operator is regularly used in mongoDB but I'm not sure how well it does perform for a huge array with around 5000 elements,it depends on your dataset size & since you're querying against `_id` then by default it will indexed so usually it should be fast enough as the search does happen on index keys & then the respective document is fetched from collection(not an entire collection scan) &not sure whether `$in` internally iterate thru passed in array or send all values at a time,Please check executionStats for more info :: using `explain` on query execution.

Answer (score 0):

> My main question is how the $in operator works. The example below has
>   an aggregate which tries to check if a primary key (object ID) is in
>   an array of object IDs.

Consider the code:

```
var OBJ_ARR = [ ObjectId("5df9b50e7b7941c4273a5369"), ObjectId("5df9b50f7b7941c4273a5525"), ObjectId("5df9b50e7b7941c4273a515f"), ObjectId("5df9b50e7b7941c4273a51ba") ]

db.test.aggregate( [
    {
      $match: {
          _id: { $in: OBJ_ARR }
      }
    }
])
```

The query tries to match each of the array elements with the documents in the collection. Since, there are four elements in the OBJ_ARR there might be four documents returned or lesser depending upon the matches.

If you have N `_id`'s in the lookup array, the operation will try to find match for *all* elements in the input array. The more number of values you have in the array, the more time it takes; the number of `ObjectId`s matter in query performance. In case you have a single element in the array, it is considered as one equal match.

From the documentation - [the $in works like an $or operator with equality checks](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/index.html#use-the-in-operator-to-match-values).

> ... what's the most efficient way of aggregating a set of documents
>   given a bunch of object IDs?

The `_id` field of the collection has a *unique index*, by default. The query, you are trying will use this index to match the documents. Running an `explain()` on a query (with a small set of test data) confirms that there is an index scan (IXSCAN) on the match operation with `$in` used with the aggregation query. That is a better performing query (as it is) becuse of the index usage. But, the aggregation query's later/following stages, size of the data set, the input array size and other factors will influence the overall performance and efficiency.

Also, see:
[Pipeline Operators and Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#pipeline-operators-and-indexes) *and*  [Aggregation Pipeline Optimization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/).